# How do I move my remote git repo to another remote git repo?

Tags: git, git-remote

I want to move my remote git repository and all its branches to a new remote repository.

old remote = `git@github.com:thunderrabbit/thunderrabbit.github.com.git`

new remote = `git@newhub.example.net:tr/tr.newrepo.git`

Comment: I know that this was a self-answer question, but the question itself is still very low quality. Maybe try adding some of the ideas that you tried or documentation that you looked at before you came up with [your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14432237/456814).

Comment: FYI, [umläute's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14435630/456814) isn't quite correct, see [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14432234/how-do-i-move-my-remote-git-repo-to-another-remote-git-repo#comment35718703_14435630).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So what none of these other answers explains too well is that if you want to
move all of your remote repository's branches to a new remote using Git's `push`
mechanism, **then you need local branch versions of each of your remote's
branches.**

You can use`git branch` to create local branches. That will create a branch
reference under your `.git/refs/heads/` directory, where all of your local
branch references are stored.

Then you can use `git push` with the `--all` and `--tags` option flags:

```bash
git push <new-remote> --all  # Push all branches under .git/refs/heads
git push <new-remote> --tags # Push all tags under .git/refs/tags
```

Note that `--all` and `--tags` can't be used together, so that's why you have to
push twice.

#### Documentation

Here's the relevant [`git push` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html):

> ```
> --all
> ```
>
> Instead of naming each ref to push, specifies that all refs under
>   `refs/heads/` be pushed.
>
> ```
> --tags
> ```
>
> All refs under `refs/tags` are pushed, in addition to refspecs explicitly
>   listed on the command line.

### `--mirror`

Note also that `--mirror` can be used to push both branch and tag references at
once, but the problem with this flag is that it pushes ***all references*** in
`.git/refs/`, not just `.git/refs/heads` and `.git/refs/tags`, which may not be
what you want to push to your remote.

For example, `--mirror` can push your remote tracking branches from your old
remote(s) that are under `.git/refs/remotes/<remote>/`, as well as other
references such as `.git/refs/original/`, which is a by-product of [`git filter-branch`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-filter-branch.html).

Answer (score 13):

In terminal on your local machine:

```
cd ~
git clone <old-remote> unique_local_name
cd unique_local_name

for remote in `git branch -r | grep -v master `; \
do git checkout --track $remote ; done

git remote add neworigin <new-remote>
git push --all neworigin
```

Comment: Is the last line (git push --all gitlab) a typo? Shouldn’t it be new origin, not gitlab?

Comment: FYI, if you want to push tags, then you also need to use `git push --tags` (it can't be used at the same time as `--all`). Also, instead of using `git checkout`, you could also use `git branch`, which will probably be faster, since you're not switching files in your working copy.

Answer (score 4):

Whole idea is to for each old remote branch do:

- checkout
- pull
- push to the new remote (do not forget about tags!)

Like that:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

new_remote_link=git@newhub.example.net:tr/tr.newrepo.git
new_remote=new_remote
old_remote_link=git@github.com:thunderrabbit/thunderrabbit.github.com.git
old_remote=origin

git remote add ${old_remote} ${old_remote_link}

git pull ${old_remote}

BRANCHES=`git ls-remote --heads ${old_remote}  | sed 's?.*refs/heads/??'`

git remote add ${new_remote} ${new_remote_link}

for branch in ${BRANCHES}; do
    git checkout ${branch}
    git pull ${old_remote} ${branch}
    git push ${new_remote} ${branch} --tags
    printf "\nlatest %s commit\n" ${branch}
    git log --pretty=format:"(%cr) %h: %s%n%n" -n1
done
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply change the URL for your `origin` repository:

```
git clone <old-remote-url> unique_local_name
cd unique_local_name
git pull --all

git remote set-url origin <new-remote-url>
git push --all
```

Comment: This isn't quite correct, if you don't have local branch versions of each of your remote branches, then they won't be pushed to the new remote. Only local branches under `.git/refs/heads/` will get pushed.