# migrate all branches + all tags from one git repo into another

Tags: git

I would like to migrate entire git repository from one repo into another (this includes all branches and all tags). So far I've found recipes how to do that for one specific branch. Is there a git-alike way to do it without looping over all branches manually?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14432234/how-do-i-move-my-remote-git-repo-to-another-remote-git-repo duplicate

Comment: What do you want to do with conflicting branch names?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I move my remote git repo to another remote git repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14432234/how-do-i-move-my-remote-git-repo-to-another-remote-git-repo)